# Fetch only calendar-events created by my application

Tags: ios, eventkit

I'm just working on a simple application that creates events in calendar (`EventKit`), I don't want to add a specific calendar for my application, I prefer leaving user free to choose on which calendars add a new event.

I think that an approach would be storing eventIdentifiers in a Plist or using Coredata, and fetch events by id every time I need... but I'm curious to know if there is a simpler and better integrated method to get only events created by my application.

Comment: I had the same issue and solved it exactly the way you're thinking of dealing with it. Don't think there is any other way.

Comment: As per my knowledge there is a way to associate bunch of events for Application, but don't have the exact idea. Did you find any things regarding this?